# Com client authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, com, client, ipc

We have a setup here where every process is signed. We have a process with SYSTEM privilege that exposes COM interfaces. We do not want processes other than the ones signed by us to use the COM interfaces. Is there any way to accomplish this? We are also exploring other Windows IPC mechanisms that could allow this. Feel free to suggest other IPC Mechanisms that makes this possible.
Currently we are sending the pid, along with the request but that can be easily spoofed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Register a custom proxy/stub or inproc handler and have the proxy or handler incorporate code which checks the signature on the binary.
2. Make all access go via an inproc COM object which performs the validation and undergoes a challenge/response process with the server. Of course that can be spoofed too if they are handy with a debugger.
3. **Just give up on it.** Even a signed process can be spoofed - use CreateProcess with the suspended flag, inject a DLL, and overwrite the entrypoint with a JMP into the DLL.  First call is a Sleep(1000) so allow it to run for 500ms, then replace your jump with the original code. Now you are running code in the DLL but the EXE hasn't been modified.

That's even without using the debugging APIs. Heck, they could patch your service to remove the check!